Inclusion exclusion formula for Betti numbers
Let $K$ be simplicial complex with $K1$ and $K2$ such that $K1 \cup K_2 = K$. Does the following hold ?
$$\beta_i (K) = \beta_i (K1) + \beta_i (K2) - \beta_i (K1 \cap K2) $$
$\beta_i$ is the i-th betti number.
Is this just inclusion-exclusion formula for i-simplices in K ? Am I missing something ?

This only works for the Euler-characteristic, not individual Betti numbers.

This is not true. Take a loop, and write it as a union of two semi-circles. The first betti number of the loop is 1, but the first betti numbers of the semi-circles and their (disconnected) intersection are zero.
